# Regex search find before and after query

Tags: python, regex, search, regex-group

So I have this sequence and I'm trying to use regex's search function to find the region before the occurrence of the query and the region after.

This is what I have

```
sequence = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
query = 'jklmnop'
```

This is what I want to end up with

```
before = 'abcdefghi'
after = 'qrstuvwxyz'
```

I tried it for the before one and it's not working. I thought this would split it into 3 groups

```
sequence = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
query = 'jklmnop'
print re.search('\w+(query)\w+',sequence).group(0)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing `query` inside a string doesn't stores the value of `query` inside that string, it simply creates a new string with the string 'query' in it.

```
>>> print '\w+(query)\w+'
\w+(query)\w+
```

You should use string formatting:

```
>>> sequence = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> query = 'jklmnop'
>>> '(\w+)({})(\w+)'.format(query)
'(\\w+)(jklmnop)(\\w+)'

>>> re.search('(\w+)({})(\w+)'.format(query),sequence).group(1)
'abcdefghi'
>>> re.search('(\w+)({})(\w+)'.format(query),sequence).group(3)
'qrstuvwxyz'
```

It's better to use `re.split` for such purposes:

```
>>> strs = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> import re
>>> before, after = re.split('jklmnop',strs)
>>> before
'abcdefghi'
>>> after
'qrstuvwxyz'
```

Comment: thanks thats a great explanation but what does format do to the {} ?

Comment: @draconisthe0ry `{}` is a place-holder that specify where the values of parameters passed to `format()` are going to be stored(substituted) in the string.
Look at some examples : http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples